# Why is it that QGIS shows only one attribute table on all layers?

Tags: qgis

I have checked the "Select Single Feature" before clicking the Attribute Table but even if I choose a different layer, only one attribute table is shown.

Comment: What do you mean by "only one attribute table"? When I right-click a layer in the layer list, then open the attribute table, then select another layer and open its attribute table i get two windows (QGis 1.8.0).

Comment: @ til_b The system picks one attribute table and keeps on showing it across all layers such that even if i change layer and click for attribute table, it keeps on showing the same attribute table.

Comment: thats weird. What happens when you open the table for layer A, then close it, then open the table for layer B? What QGis version are you using?

Comment: Hi til_b. Thank you for responding. Even if I close the attribute table for layer A and open the table for layer B, it keeps on showing the same attribute table. Im running it on Mac and I downloaded the QGIS v 1.8.0-2 from here: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis